# Snap7 + Ni Labwindows/CVI

Tags: dllimport, cvi, labwindows, snap7

Hi guys i am working on a project where my client wants to use Siemens S7 1200 to control some pneumatic tools and an interface on labwindows Cvi.
I downloaded SP7 ( snap 7)  on a try to communicate with my plc but i found myself blocked since the downloaded file contains only a DLL file and a lib file whit no.h file ( header file )
could anyone tell me how to use snap 7 properly on labwindows ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK if you want to use Snap7, you'll have to download the source (C++) and then manipulate it to work with LabWindows.

S7-1200s also have the following communication options.

Free-of-charge:

- [Modbus/TCP](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/102020340)
- [Socket services ("Open user communication")](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/109747710)
- [MQTT unencrypted](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/109748872)

For a fee:

- [OPC UA](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/109775168)

More here:
[Communication methods for S7-1200/1500 PLCs](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/109780503)

Personal opinion: if you don't have many data points to monitor, I would go with Modbus/TCP.